# Why am I getting segmentation fault for this program?

Tags: c

I have to write a program which reads dates and todo-s as command line arguments and puts these in a text-file (line by line).

**Correct input:**

```
./todo 13:58 todo1 00:00 todo2 08:30 todo3
```

**Wrong input:**

```
./todo 13:58 todo1 24:00 todo2 08:30 todo3 or ./todo 13:58 todo1 todo2 00:00 08:30 todo3
```

Correct **todolist.txt** file:

```
13:58 - todo1
00:00 - todo2
08:30 - todo3
```

The code is compiled successfully, but when I run the program, I get segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isValidTime(char* argv)
{
    char hour[2] = {0};
    char minute[2] = {0};

    for (unsigned int i = 0; argv[i] != ':'; i++) {
        hour[i] = argv[i];
    }
    int hourNum = atoi(hour);
    if (!(hourNum >= 0 && hourNum < 24)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 3; i < sizeof(*argv) / sizeof(argv[0]); i++) {
        minute[i] = argv[i];
    }
    int minuteNum = atoi(minute);
    if (!(minuteNum >= 0 && minuteNum < 60)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool isValidTodo(char* argv)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(*argv) / sizeof(argv[0]); i++) {
        if (!(argv[i] >= 'a' && argv[i] <= 'z')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Incorrect input!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("todolist.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File failed to open.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (!(isValidTime(argv[2 * i - 1]) && isValidTodo(argv[2 * i]))) {
            printf("Incorrect input!\n");
        }
        fprintf(file, "%s - %s\n", argv[2 * i - 1], argv[2 * i]);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please only tag the language you are using. You compile this code either as C or as C++, but unlikely you need it to compile in both languages. I assumed it is C

Comment: `argv[2 * i - 1]` is probably going past the end of argv[];  argv[] is only defined for [0..argc).   Also, in isValidTodo, sizeof *argv/sizeof(argv[0]) is always 1.  The length of a string is discovered by strlen().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is because of this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (!(isValidTime(argv[2 * i - 1]) && isValidTodo(argv[2 * i]))) {
        printf("Incorrect input!\n");
    }
    fprintf(file, "%s - %s\n", argv[2 * i - 1], argv[2 * i]);
}
```

You are getting `argc` number of arguments, but then you index the array using `argv[2 * i - 1]`. Say you have 4 arguments - you are going to try to index element `2 * 4 - 1`, that is, element `7` which would be outside the array, hence the segmentation fault.

You probably need to just remove the `2 *` part, if your goal is to do something with the previous and current elements.

Another issue I see is this code:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; argv[i] != ':'; i++) {
    hour[i] = argv[i];
}
```

In case there is no `:` in the argument, you will loop indefinitely and will get another segmentation fault for `hour[i]` and `argv[i]`.